# Override onOptionsItemSelected in a fragment to not call it in the container activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment who has 2 faces like it was two separated activities, i want the home button transforms into back arrow when it is in the face two and open the menu when it is in the face 1; the toolbar is outside the fragment. and the code to display the menu is in the container.

[image]

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {     

// in the container activity "home"
//calls a menú i dont want to show it when i'm on the face 2

int id = item.getItemId();


    if (face ==  2 && id == android.R.id.home) {

        show_face(false);//animation true = show face 2; false = show face 1
    return true;

    }else
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

I returned true because of:

"boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here."

but i think i misunderstood it.

PD: I want the code be in the fragment for managment purposes because i use too many fragments.

excuse my writing, I'm no good English.